# C# Multicast UDP Packet Drops while storing objects

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

I'm currently subscribing to a multicast UDP. It streams multiple messages, each about 80 bytes, in a single max 1000 byte packet. As the packets come in, I parse them into objects and then store them in a dictionary.

Each packet I receive comes with a sequential number so that I know if I've dropped any packets.

After about 10k packets received, I start to drop packets here and there.

```
securityDefinition xyz = new securityDefinition(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5...etc);
if (!secDefs.ContainsKey(securityID))
{
    secDefs.Add(securityID, xyz); //THIS WILL CAUSE DROPS EVENTUALLY
    secDefs.Add(securityID, null); //THIS WORKS JUST FINE
}
else
{
    //A repeat definition is received and assuming all 
    //sequence numbers in the packet line up sequentially, I know i am done

    //However if there is a drop somewhere (gap in sequence number),
    //I know I am missing something
}
```

securityDefinition is a class containing roughly 15 ints, 10 decimals and 5 strings (<10 characters each).

Is there a faster way to store these objects in real time that can keep up with the fast UDP feed? I have tried making securityDefinition a struct, I have tried storing the data in a datatable, I have tried adding the secDef to a list and queue. Same issue with all.

It seems the only bottleneck is putting the objects in the dictionary. Creating the object and checking the dictionary to see if it already exists seems fine.

EDIT:
To clarify a few things - the security definitions come in from a server in a loop. There are roughly 1,000,000 definitions. Once they all are sent, they are then sent again, over and over. When my program starts, I need to initialize all the definitions. Once I get a repeat, I know I am done and can close this connection. However, if i receive a packet at sequence number 1, and the next packet is sequence number 3, I know I have dropped packet 2 and have no way of recovering it.

Comment: It looks like you are getting duplicate keys in the dictionary and not really dropping anything.  You may want a dictionary defined like : Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: Maybe the check can be removed entirely, since I _believe_ `Add` will do some checking already (to determine if an exception should be thrown). I realize you mentioned it wasn’t part of the bottleneck, but if your entries are known to be unique, then why not just do `secdefs[securityId] = xyz`?  Also, if you know a “max number of definitions” you’ll get, maybe initializing the capacity of the dictionary would help, so it doesn’t have to get resized.

Comment: "no way of recovering it" -- I thought you said they are repeated in a loop, then you can just get the missing data on the next iteration.

Comment: The sequence numbers do not start back at 0 on the next iteration, they just keep building on each other. The only thing I can think of is that if I know there were 10 drops on iteration 1, I would keep letting it loop until 10 new secDefs were found and added. I guess this would work but it's pretty hacky and would obviously prefer a solution limiting/eliminating drops to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> pkts = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();


//IN THE RECEIVER THREAD...
void ProductDefinitionReceiver()
{
    while (!secDefsComplete)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        s.Receive(data);
        pkts.Enqueue(data);
    }
}

//IN A SEPARATE THREAD:
public void processPacketQueue()
{
    int dumped = 0;
    byte[] pkt;
    while (!secDefsComplete)
    {
        while (pkts.TryDequeue(out pkt))
        {
            if (!secDefsComplete)
            {
                //processPkt includes the parsing and inserting the secDef object into the dictionary.
                processPkt(pkt);
            }
            else
            {
                dumped++;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Dumped: " + dumped);
}
```